# Finding a path with minimal number of turns on a grid?

Tags: path-finding, tilemap, grid

There is a path, generated by my implementation of **A***, where **diagonals aren't allowed**, and the **heuristics is the Manhattan distance**.

Is there a way to **always or nearly always find a path with the least amount of turns**? Even if it's a **bit longer**, and even if it **costs more computationall**y.

Or is there a way to **algorithmically "fix" a path** later? Like on the image below, **cut those long detours** and **replace them** with those **blue parts**.

My current version is far from optimal, both length-wise, and both turn-wise.
I also tried **multiplying the heuristic value** of a tile, if:

- it isn't going in the same direction as the line made from the previous 2 tiles. But that didn't help either.

[image]

Comment: Why do you even have those detours? Especially the second one that hugs the wall. That shouldn't happen with A*

Comment: Köszi, I knew that something was not quite right, there was a banal typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First fix your A* implementation so that it will find the shortest path.

Adjust the *cost* of the turn instead of the heuristic. This means that when you generate the neighbours the one going straight ahead gets cost 1 and the one where you make a left or right gets a higher cost depending on how large a detour you accept.

This means that every tile can get *up to 4 nodes* in the A* graph, one for each direction the entity can come from. For the purpose of A* you have to treat them as separate nodes.

It is fine if the heuristic *underestimates* the total cost, but not if it overestimates. So manhattan will still be good enough.